# PHP Function Returning the Last Date Values Only

Tags: php, html

Basically I am creating an attendance script and trying to get attendance details from sql tables for Current month and year. But the following functions are returning only last recorded values and not from the entire record. Please help.

Here is my php code/function;

```
function get_month_attendance(){
global $db, $mybb;
$month = date('m');
$year = date('y');

$query = $db->query("
    SELECT t.*, a.*
    FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."teachers t
    LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_PREFIX."teacher_attendance a ON(a.tid=t.tid)
    WHERE t.teacher_approve != '0'
    GROUP BY t.teacher_name
    ORDER BY t.tid ASC");
$month_attendance = '';
while($t = $db->fetch_array($query))
{
    // Gender
    if ($t['teacher_gender'] == "Male")
    {
        $name_prefix = 'Sir ';
    }
    elseif ($t['teacher_gender'] == "Female")
    {
        $name_prefix = 'Miss ';
    }
        $a = $t;
        
        $a_1 = get_day_attendance($a, "01");
        $a_2 = get_day_attendance($a, "02");
        $a_3 = get_day_attendance($a, "03");
        $a_4 = get_day_attendance($a, "04");
        $a_5 = get_day_attendance($a, "05");
        $a_6 = get_day_attendance($a, "06");
        $a_7 = get_day_attendance($a, "07");
        $a_8 = get_day_attendance($a, "08");
        $a_9 = get_day_attendance($a, "09");
        $a_10 = get_day_attendance($a, "10");
        
        $a_11 = get_day_attendance($a, "11");
        $a_12 = get_day_attendance($a, "12");
        $a_13 = get_day_attendance($a, "13");
        $a_14 = get_day_attendance($a, "14");
        $a_15 = get_day_attendance($a, "15");
        $a_16 = get_day_attendance($a, "16");
        $a_17 = get_day_attendance($a, "17");
        $a_18 = get_day_attendance($a, "18");
        $a_19 = get_day_attendance($a, "19");
        $a_20 = get_day_attendance($a, "20");
        
        $a_21 = get_day_attendance($a, "21");
        $a_22 = get_day_attendance($a, "22");
        $a_23 = get_day_attendance($a, "23");
        $a_24 = get_day_attendance($a, "24");
        $a_25 = get_day_attendance($a, "25");
        $a_26 = get_day_attendance($a, "26");
        $a_27 = get_day_attendance($a, "27");
        $a_28 = get_day_attendance($a, "28");
        $a_29 = get_day_attendance($a, "29");
        $a_30 = get_day_attendance($a, "30");

        $a_31 = get_day_attendance($a, "31");

    $bg_color = alt_trow();
    $month_attendance .= '
        <tr>
            <td class="'.$bg_color.'">
                <a href="teachers.php?action=view_profile&tid='.$t['tid'].'">'.$name_prefix.$t['teacher_name'].'</a>
            </td>
            '.$a_1.'
            '.$a_2.'
            '.$a_3.'
            '.$a_4.'
            '.$a_5.'
            '.$a_6.'
            '.$a_7.'
            '.$a_8.'
            '.$a_9.'
            '.$a_10.'
            '.$a_11.'
            '.$a_12.'
            '.$a_13.'
            '.$a_14.'
            '.$a_15.'
            '.$a_16.'
            '.$a_17.'
            '.$a_18.'
            '.$a_19.'
            '.$a_20.'
            '.$a_21.'
            '.$a_22.'
            '.$a_23.'
            '.$a_24.'
            '.$a_25.'
            '.$a_26.'
            '.$a_27.'
            '.$a_28.'
            '.$a_29.'
            '.$a_30.'
            '.$a_31.'
        </tr>
    ';
}

if (!$month_attendance)
{
    $month_attendance = '<tr><td colspan="32" align="center">No Teacher(s).</td></tr>';
}
return $month_attendance;}

function get_day_attendance($a, $day){
$att_text = 'A';
$att_color = '#FF7777';
if ($a['day'] == $day)
{
    if ($a['aid']) // It means that the attendance has been Recorded and hence the Teacher either Present or is on Leave
    {
        if (!empty($a['enter_time'])) // It means the Teacher is Present
        {
            $enter_time = 'Entered on: '.date("H:i A", $a['enter_time']);
            $exit_time = '';
            if (!empty($a['exit_time'])) // It means that the Teacher is Exited
            {
                $exit_time = '<br />Exited on: '.date("H:i A", $a['exit_time']);
            }
            $att_text = '<div class="tooltip">P<span class="tooltiptext" style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">'.$enter_time.''.$exit_time.'</span></div>';
            $att_color = '#00FF54';
        }
        else
        {
            if ($a['leave'] == "1") // It means that the Teacher is on Leave
            {
                $att_text = '<div class="tooltip">L<span class="tooltiptext" style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">Reason: '.$a['leave_reason'].'</span></div>';
                $att_color = '#F9FF00';
            }
        }
    }
}
return $attendance_bit .= '<td style="background: '.$att_color.';" width="2.5%" align="center">'.$att_text.'</td>';}
```

This is my PHP page code where some HTML is also included;

```
$month_attendance = get_month_attendance();
$page_title = 'Month-Wise Attendance Record';
$page_show = '
<html>
<head>
    <title>'.$page_title.'</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="teachers_js.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="teachers_css.css" />
</head>
<body>
'.$header.'
    <div id="container">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" class="tborder">
        <tr>
            <td class="tcat" colspan="32">'.$page_title.'</td>
        <tr>
            <td class="tcat2" width="30%">Name</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">1</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">2</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">3</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">4</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">5</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">6</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">7</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">8</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">9</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">10</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">11</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">12</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">13</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">14</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">15</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">16</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">17</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">18</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">19</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">20</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">21</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">22</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">23</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">24</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">25</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">26</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">27</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">28</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">29</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">30</td>
            <td class="tcat2" width="2.5%">31</td>
        </tr>
        '.$month_attendance.'
    </table>
    <br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>';
```

and this is what I get when the function `get_month_attendance()` is called;
[image]

and this is my sql table image
[image]

Comment: We can't see the contents of your SQL tables or your query result so we really have no idea if the code is reporting it accurately or not. Please provide a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Hello @ADyson, I have updated the first post above.

Comment: Is that the result of your query, or the raw table data?

Comment: only a glimpse of my Table data. Entire table is 2 to 3 pages long.

Comment: So what result does your query produce? Because that's the data which PHP is working with. It seems to be grouping it by teacher which might only produce one row per teacher I think, even though you have no aggregate function so using a group by doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The results are posted above in image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IZWu.jpg

Comment: That's what your _PHP_ produces. I'm asking what the _SQL_ produces. Run your query directly in phpMyAdmin and show what it outputs.

Comment: It is returning only one result. :/

Comment: One result only? Or one per teacher? But like I said it's probably because of the group by - no idea why you wanted that?

Comment: One result per teacher. Also GROUP BY is used here just to group the teacher's results other wise the query is fetching all the records for 10 teachers.

Comment: But it's making it so that you have 1 result per teacher, that's what GROUP BY does! Surely you _want_ all the results for each teacher so you can get all the data for all the days?